# Java JsonPath: Insert object into another object

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am using the [JayWay JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to manipulate JSON objects.

I want to insert a JSON object into a JSON array:

```json
### before
{
  "students": []
}

### after
{
  "students": [{"id": 1, "name": "Bob"}]
}
```

Somehow I cannot accomplish this in JsonPath. If I add the object as a string, it is not recognized as a JSON object:

```java
var context = JsonPath.parse("{\"students\":  []}");
context.add("students", "{\"id\":  1, \"name\":  \"Bob\"}");

System.out.println(context.jsonString());
// > {"students":["{\"id\":  1, \"lastName\":  \"Bob\"}"]}
```

If I try to parse the object, JsonPath adds an empty object:

```java
var context = JsonPath.parse("{\"students\":  []}");
context.add("students", JsonPath.parse("{\"id\":  1, \"name\":  \"Bob\"}"));

System.out.println(context.jsonString());
// > {"students":[{}]}
```

How can I insert the JSON object into the array?

Comment: Is it com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.json()` method:

```
    var context = JsonPath.parse("{\"students\":  []}");
    Object entryToAdd = JsonPath.parse("{\"id\":  1, \"name\":  \"Bob\"}").json();
    String updatedJson = context.add("students", entryToAdd).jsonString();
    System.out.println(updatedJson);
```

prints

> {"students":[{"id":1,"name":"Bob"}]}